# Hooking a fridge/freezer and washing machine to one cold water supply

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, washing-machine

Is it possible to connect a fridge/freezer and a washing machine to a single cold water supply? I need to know what sort of adapter I would need for the water supply to feed both appliances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is usually possible as long as you have sufficient pressure and flow if they both run at the same time.

Examples are:
[image: push fitting with valve]

[image: threaded]

Comment: would be helpful if you added a googleable item name. I guess, that is some sort of "Y 2 Way connector"

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica the issue is going to be that there's about a dozen different names/types of these connectors for each type of supply the water could be coming from (copper, pex, galvanized pipe, PVC, a garden hose spigot, the actual washer hookup fitting, etc.) We would need to at least know more details to do that.